# Assign Resulted Value to Third TextBox Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have three textboxes. I want to get the value from the first 2 textboxes, calculate the value and then assign the result to the 3rd textbox. To achieve this, i have done something like following in jquery;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function myfunction() {
        $("#TxBx_MarksObtained").change(function () {
            //var value = $(this).val();
            var a = $("#TextBoxTotalMarks").val();
            var b = $("#TxBx_MarksObtained").val();
            var c = (b * 100 / a).toFixed(2);
            $("#TextBoxMarksInPercent").val(c);
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Now, the problem is, when i focus on `TextBoxTotalMarks` and enter the value, and for `TxBx_MarksObtained` too, Everythings works great and the result is assign to `TextBoxMarksInPercent`. 
However, when i change my focus to another textbox (somewhere else in form) and then come back and change the value of `TextBoxTotalMarks` and `TxBx_MarksObtained`. I dont see any changes in `TextBoxMarksInPercent`. 
**What i am getting wrong? 

Why my value isn't updated after comming back from another textbox?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a error in `doc ready` handler:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function myfunction() {
   //-------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^-----this should not be here
```

try this way i would suggest you to use `.blur() or .focus() or .key()events`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TxBx_MarksObtained, #TxBx_MarksObtained").keyup(function () {
    // ------------------------------------------^^^^^^--keyup instead of change.
        var a = $("#TextBoxTotalMarks").val();
        var b = $("#TxBx_MarksObtained").val();
        var c = (b * 100 / a).toFixed(2);
        $("#TextBoxMarksInPercent").val(c);
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#TxBx_MarksObtained, #TextBoxTotalMarks").change(function () {//for both text boxes
            //var value = $(this).val();
            var a = $("#TextBoxTotalMarks").val();
            var b = $("#TxBx_MarksObtained").val();
            var c = (b * 100 / a).toFixed(2);
            $("#TextBoxMarksInPercent").val(c);
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try `blur` in place of `change` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try focusout() instead of change()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready( function ()
    {
        $("#TxBx_MarksObtained, #TextBoxTotalMarks").focusout(function () {//for both text boxes
            //var value = $(this).val();
            var a = $("#TextBoxTotalMarks").val();
            var b = $("#TxBx_MarksObtained").val();
            var c = (b * 100 / a).toFixed(2);
            $("#TextBoxMarksInPercent").val(c);
        }); 
    });
</script>
```